# Magento 2.3 - Product stock alert not display

Tags: magento2, php, module, admin, magento2.2

I use Magento 2.3 and I create a custom theme based on Luma theme.

I enable the Magento_ProductAlert module from backend but the message "**notify me when this product is in stock**" is not display in frontend.

How I can check / fix this issue?

I will add here my backend settings:

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Product Alerts
```

[image]

```
 Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options
```

[image]

```
and this is my simple product configuration:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not showing because you are allowing Backorders
[image]

Try to change this into 
[image]

Run

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

```
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

Comment: indeed @Ylgen Guxholli this was the problem, thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful .

Comment: Glad it`s solved @Robert :).

Answer (score 0):

You can debug why this happened.

Open **vendor/magento/module-product-alert/Block/Product/View/Stock.php** and check following code snippet

```
/**
 * Prepare stock info
 *
 * @param string $template
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTemplate($template)
{
    if (!$this->_helper->isStockAlertAllowed() || !$this->getProduct() || $this->getProduct()->isAvailable()) {
        $template = '';
    } else {
        $this->setSignupUrl($this->_helper->getSaveUrl('stock'));
    }
    return parent::setTemplate($template);
}
```

You need to check **$this->getProduct()->isAvailable()**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php

```
/**
 * Check whether the product type or stock allows to purchase the product
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAvailable()
{
    return $this->_catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck() || $this->getTypeInstance()->isSalable($this);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help, can I ask you how I can see why is happened this? what I need to put there in the function? or what I need to do?

Comment: Hi @Sohel Rana do you see my question? can you help me with this? thanks

Comment: You can add log or something else. Check updated answer where you check.